# How to mock an ES6 class that is a named export in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

Jest documentation clearly shows how to [manually mock an ES6 class](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) when it is a default export. For example, here's a class that is exported as default:

```
class QueryService {
    query(queryText: string): Promise<any> {
        // ----- Query the API -----

        // ----- Return the result -----
        return Promise.resolve({
            data: {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                name: 'Alphabet Company'
            }
        });
    }
}

export default QueryService;
```

And it is mocked as follows:

```
const mockQuery = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./QueryService', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {query: mockQuery};
    });
});
```

However how do I mock this class if it was a named export? I couldn't figure this out!

Here's my [full repo with this example](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/enzyme-playground/blob/master/src/pages/MockClassPage/useQuery.test.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8532.

Summary:

```
const mockQuery = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./QueryService', () => {
    return {
        QueryService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return { query: mockQuery };
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find a manual mock for the same thing in the issue. Do you have any example for manual mock of a class that is a named export?

Answer (score 0):

For a class you want to use the `spyOn()` function which is specifically designed for classes